# BCP utility 13.0 bug with varbinary(max)

Tags: sql-server-2016, bcp, varbinarymax

I followed Microsoft's command `bcp db..someTable ​format ...` to create a fmt file.
The table contains a varbinary(max) column.

The resultant fmt file looks like this

> 13.0
>
> 1
>
> 1    SQLCHAR   0   0   "\r\n" ...

When I use this fmt file to `bcp "SELECT bin FROM..." queryout...` 
I get a corrupted PNG file.

I went back to check older fmt files, and they look like this

> 10.0
>
> 1
>
> 1    **SQLBINARY** ...

So I edited the new fmt file by changing the data type column to **SQLBINARY** and it works! The PNG file can now be opened.

Is this a bug with bcp 13.0? Why is the varbinary(max) column becoming SQLCHAR in the generated format file?

Comment: It's not corrupted, it's just a `0x` hex character string. You need the `-n` or `-N` option, see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#n

Comment: @Charlieface thanks! The Microsoft example of `bcp format` was using -c! You are right with -n